# How can i show a PPT preview in angular application? I donot want to use ngx-doc-viewer

Tags: node.js, angular

How can i show a PPT preview in angular application?

I want to show some ppt saved in server location.I donot want to use ngx-doc-viewer because it will append https://docs.google.com/gview+fileurl without appending "https://docs.google.com/gview" is it possible ?.

Answer (score 1):

Using the iFrame tag within the HTML file is often a nice way to display stored files like PPTs. You can define the path within your TS file or pass it back from the template. To validate that path, you probably need to use the DomSanitizer

Comment: i tried this  as you mentioned and it did not work.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src-ljebsq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: what i figured out is it will work for images but about documents like PPT it did not work

Comment: You are right, the file is only downloaded but not displayed. Is the Content-Type within the response header set to text/html?